# using a DisplayActionSheet from viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to use a DisplayActionSheet inside my viewmodel, that gets called via a command that gets called by the press of a button. the problem is i dont have access to DisplayActionSheet (the name DisplayActionSheet doesnt exist in current context). Normally i would have just put it in the page.xaml.cs file but the problem is that i am trying to remove a label everytime a certain action is taken, and the collection of labels is located inside the viewmodel. i hope you understand my question.

```
<ImageButton 
                                Source="Kurv.png"
                                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveOrdreCommand, Source={x:Reference OrdreListe}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                
                            />
```

and

```
public ICommand RemoveOrdreCommand => new Command(RemoveOrdreItem);
    public async void RemoveOrdreItem(object o)
    {
        string svar = await *DisplayActionSheet*("Vil du tage imod denne ordre?", "Annullér", null, "Ja", "Nej");
        OrdreItem ordreItemBeingRemoved = o as OrdreItem;
        if (svar == "Ja")
        {
            OrdreItems.Remove(ordreItemBeingRemoved); 
        }

    }
```

the ** is where it gives me the error.
if i try putting it as an eventhandler in the page.xaml.cs i cant access my observable collection of OrdreItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayActionSheet` is a method of `Page`.  To access it from your VM, you can do this

```
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet("Vil du tage imod denne ordre?", "Annullér", null, "Ja", "Nej");
```